# Facing javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng

Facing following error while executing second test in my testng class. 
This error is coming on action class moveToelement method.

If I run one TC at a time its working fine, but when my first testcase got executed and second test start execution its throwing error.
**javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.**

If I donot use action class and directly access element it throwing (even after putting proper wait)
**element not interactable**

```
    @Test(enabled = true, priority = 1)
      public void test_A(){
      // test A code
     }

    @Test(enabled = true,priority = 2)
      public void test_B(){
       // code to redirect to other page
       MethodLibrary.click("ele_xpath"); //Error
      // here click method include finding element, movetoelement and 
      click
      }
```

element: xpath //*[@id="09876"]/a/img

```
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d menu" style="top:0px; 
      left:319px; width:21px; height:21px;">
      <img class="btnimg"src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" 
       alt="Menu for Company*+" title="">
    </a>
```

Comment: Please post your code and the element type, is it displayed?

Comment: updated query with code and element..

Comment: Why are you using xpath with an elements which has ID, use ID instead xpath.
In general the errors occurs when the element is hidden, why are you using Action class? What are you trying to do with actions?

Comment: 1. div/a/img 
ID is of 'div', not the img element which I need to click. 
2. as I mentioned in query if dont use action class and use direct click its giving 'element is not intractable' even if I put a wait.